# Py/Tk - Tkinter: redirect STDOUT to window label text box

Tags: python, tkinter, label

I'm trying to get the stdout of the "securityonion" function to print to the window that that function spawns. How do I do this?

I've seen several other posts on the same subject but cannot wrap my head around how to achieve this. I'm not shooting for OO code in this scenario, if you try my entire script out, you'll see that things are launching splendidly. I just need stdout to appear in the window that I create in said function.

Sorry, big-time Tkinter noob.

```
from Tkinter import *
import Tkinter as tk
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
import os
import time
import sys
from scapy.all import *

def terminal():
    window = tk.Toplevel(root)
    window.title("Terminal")
    termf = Frame(window, height=700, width=700)
    termf.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=YES)
    wid = termf.winfo_id()
    os.system('xterm -into %d -geometry 700x700 -sb &' % wid)

def wazuh():
    pass

def securityonion():
    window = tk.Toplevel(root)
    window.resizable(0,0)
    window.title("Security Onion Bomb")
    list = open("dests.txt").readlines()
    for x in list:
        packet = IP(dst=x,src="10.10.10.10")/TCP(dport=999,sport=1234)/"iamhaxor"
        send(packet)
        print("A PACKET HAS BEEN SENT TO " + x)
        time.sleep(2)

def endpoint():
    pass

def help():
    pass

#setup main window
root = Tk()
img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("bluetools.png"))
panel = Label(root, image = img)
panel.pack(side = "bottom", fill = "both", expand = "yes")
root.title("Optometry")
menubar = Menu(root)
root.geometry("500x400")
root.resizable(0,0)
filemenu = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)

# tools menu
filemenu.add_command(label="Launch Terminal", command=terminal)
filemenu.add_command(label="Wazuh Bomb", command=wazuh)
filemenu.add_command(label="Security Onion Bomb", command=securityonion)
filemenu.add_command(label="Endpoint Bomb", command=endpoint)
filemenu.add_command(label="Exit", command=root.quit)
menubar.add_cascade(label="Tools", menu=filemenu)

# help menu
helpmenu = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
helpmenu.add_command(label="About...", command=help)
menubar.add_cascade(label="Help", menu=helpmenu)
root.config(menu=menubar)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just replace the `print("A PACKET HAS BEEN SENT TO " + x)` with:

```
Label(window, text="A PACKET HAS BEEN SENT TO " + x).pack(fill="both", expand=True)
```

Comment: So simple, I couldn't even imagine doing it that way. That's the beauty of python. Thank you very much Nae. Marked as answer.

Answer (score 0):

I did something like this once, where stdout + stderr needed to be redirected to a tkinter textbox. It was all object-oriented, but you should be able to extract the relevant functions. [Here's](https://github.com/riley-martine/cellular-automata-cryptography/blob/master/main.py) the running code and here's the important part:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk, DISABLED, NORMAL, END

def __init__(self):
    tk.Tk.__init__(self)
    self.create_widgets()

    # If .buf exists, clear it.
    with open('.buf', 'w'):
        pass
    # Set stdout to output to .buf
    # This allows us to display a virtual terminal
    # that intercepts print(info) statements from imported classes
    sys.stdout = open(".buf", 'a')

    # Check and refresh buf -- see function for details
    self.read_std_out()

def create_widgets(self):
    ...
    info_box = ttk.Frame(self, borderwidth=1)
    self.info_text = tk.Text(info_box, bg="grey")

    self.info_text.insert(
        END, "This is printed at the beginning of the textbox!\n")
    self.info_text.config(state=DISABLED)
    self.info_text.grid(column=1, row=1)
    ...


def read_std_out(self):
    """Put stdout messages into the info_box. Called once, auto-refreshes"""
    sys.stdout.flush()  # Force write
    with open('.buf', 'r') as buf:
        read = buf.read()
        if read:  # Do not write if empty
            self.add_info(read)
    with open('.buf', 'w'):
        pass  # Clear file

    sys.stdout = open(".buf", 'a')
    self.after(1000, self.read_std_out)  # Call this again soon

def add_info(self, info):
    """Add informational message to info box. Use instead of print().
    arguments: (str) info
    effects: add line with info printed to screen in info box"""

    self.info_text.config(state=NORMAL)
    info = "> " + str(info) + "\n"
    self.info_text.insert(END, info)
    self.info_text.see(END)
    self.info_text.config(state=DISABLED)
```

I can't say I really still understand too much of what's going on, but hopefully some of my old code is useful.

Comment: Here's an image showing what it looks like: [imgur link](http://imgur.com/yvZVgKAl.png)